# Some links are still visible after logging out in drupal8

Tags: 8, users, navigation

The question is clear from the title itself , after logging out i can see some view links , one on the side navigation menu and two on the main navigation . I checked the view permission , but its same as the other view which are not visible . Any idea ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am sure you would have checked. Just for point out. Did you check permission as two places (1) Views permission, which you can find at views UI, under page setting (2) Permission of Entire that Navigation block under blocks layout.

Comment: Just form the image, If you logged out why `Log out` link still visible...:)

Comment: @CodeNext +1 : D

Comment: Thats another bugg :))

Comment: @CodeNext Thanks i have to give view permisssion under views and it worked for the side navigation link , and my doubt is i have the same permission for all other views , it open and i dint given restricted as to **view on authenticated users only**

Comment: can you suggest a view to hide logout ? or why it is still visible ??

Comment: Ok, Just came back. let me check. Are you using any Module like Menu link Attribute, to give permission to items..I guess no!

Comment: nope , i use link module only

Comment: *my doubt is i have the same permission for all other views , it open and i dint given restricted as to view on authenticated users only* I did not get this part, Please can you explain like, "What you provided and what you are getting, and actually what it should be?"

Comment: Actually the problem is solved when i restricted the views that pops out. Now the problem is logout link

Comment: I am just guessing , can you check you cache, links sometime does not disappear, it caching is not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, you check the permission at two places

(1) Views permission, which you can find at views UI, under page setting, so from there you can apply the Role restriction.

(2) Permission of Entire that Navigation block under blocks layout, Which allows the display of entire block.

Comment: Can you cache clear/re-build the cache, to solve the issue of logout link.

Comment: You are using just Mani navigation menu, right? Are you not using `User account menu`?

Comment: oh my bad .'main navigation' :) . yes there is a logout **user account menu** which is okay and another login in the **main navigation** , so i disabled the main navigation logout , problem solved :)

Comment: So all bugs now disappeared..:)..Happy coding.

Comment: aha yes  thumps up :))